# Try except in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a function in my models.py that adds the news I pass to it via a URL using OpenGraph. This process works fine, but there are some websites that give me an error, how can I use a try except to control this error and the application does not crash?

When the error occurs, I would like the application in the admin panel to return me to the same place where it was before, but indicating the error.

Best regards and thank you very much!

My models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Título", null=True, blank=True)
content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Contenido", null=True, blank=True)
published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Fecha de publicación", default=now, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Imagen", upload_to="blog", null=True, blank=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(UserManegement, verbose_name="Autor", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categorias", related_name="get_posts")
url_web = models.URLField(verbose_name="URL", null=True, blank=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de creacion')
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Fecha de ediccion')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "entrada"
    verbose_name_plural = "entradas"
    ordering = ['-created']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

The function in which I want to insert the try except. It is in the same models.py:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Post)
def url_processor(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    if instance.url_web:

        title, description, image = web_preview(instance.url_web)

        instance.title = title
        instance.content = description
    
        path = 'blog/' + uuid.uuid4().hex + '.png'
        instance.image = path
        img_data = requests.get(image).content
        with open('media/' + path, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(img_data)
    else:
        return
```

This is the error when entering this url: [Web error](https://www.enfermeria21.com/diario-dicen/la-oms-da-luz-verde-a-que-las-mujeres-embarazadas-se-vacunen-contra-la-covid-19/)

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?
```

The error from what I have been seeing, is due to the 21 of the URL, which the Python request library in version 3.6.10 takes it as an error. It only happens with URLs that have some number in their domain.

Comment: can you post your error message? and you want to catch all kinds of error there and redirect to the previous page??

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I have already put it in the main post. And yes, to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `signals` use this code in model `clean` method.

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

```
Class YourModel(models.Model):
    # fields

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # your signal code here
        except:
            raise ValidationError('Your message')
```

Comment: This works, but it shows me the error screen, and only if I hit back, it shows me the error message. Any way to do that redirect without going through the error page?

Comment: Just missed that part, just add the `return HttpResponseRedirect`

Comment: I did that, but I keep getting this new error: "<Post: 403 Forbidden>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.  Is this because of my url_processor function, that I am not telling it an ID for the category?

Comment: Try using direct `redirect` use, `from django.shortcuts import redirect` and then `redirect(request.path_info)`

Comment: Nothing, the same problem remains.

Comment: Try the above code, its the last option. Hope it works.

Comment: This works, but it does not redirect me. It shows me the Django error screen with the error I write to it. I will keep looking for a solution. Thanks for everything.